# web page design in html

Tags: php, html

hai

I want to create a web page like left and right side image, middle portion content. My problem is that the content must be display under both images. I know the cell padding is not a good idea. Some thing like div is correct way. Does any one know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want an image in top left & right corner and the content below that but leaving enough space to the right and left?

in this case you can put a `<header>` (HTML5) or `<div>` where you put in the images, one floated left, one floated right and then another `<div>` with the appropriate paddings and `clear: both;` (so that the content starts below the floats) for the content.